# Upload/Attach Video/Document Files in NewsFeed for MYSite

Tags: 2013, newsfeed

Can we attach/upload video or document file on NewsFeed Post like images can be uploaded and posted?

Can this be achieved using OOB and how?

How can I customize NewsFeed Webpart programmatically to achieve this, help/links are appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of accommodating this request, out of box, it already has this functionality in SharePoint 2013 for attaching images.

**Out-of-Box Newsfeed (Images)**

SharePoint 2013 allows you to post short messages (or “microblogs”) to the Newsfeed stream. Posting a message in a Newsfeed conversation is like posting an update on a social network like Twitter. But the goal for most organizations is for Newsfeed conversations to facilitate internal communication. [ [Source](http://blog.beezix.com/2013/03/22/getting-social-in-sharepoint-2013-with-newsfeed/) ]

To post a new message:

1. Open your Newsfeed by [Clicking] NEWSFEED.
2. To change who to share with, [Click] the group next to SHARE WITH and choose a group.
3. Type a message into the field below.
4. To add an image, [Click] , then BROWSE to find an image. Choose an image, then [Click] OPEN, UPLOAD.
5. [Click] POST.

To respond to a Newsfeed post:

1. [Click] REPLY.
2. Type a message and/or attach an image.
3. [Click] POST.

---

**Newsfeed (Programatically) - Attaching Images**

In terms of implementation, you can embed images into posts by doing the following:

- Create a SocialAttachment object that represents the image. The SocialAttachment specifies the SocialAttachmentKind.Image field and the URI of the image file.
- Add the image object to the Attachment property of the SocialPostCreationData object that's used to create the post.

[ [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn232144.aspx) ] Detailed Steps and [Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn232144.aspx#bkmk_addImage)

---

**Newsfeed (Programatically) - Attaching Videos**

In terms of implementation, you can embed videos into posts by doing the following:

- Get the SocialAttachment object that represents the video attachment by using the SocialFeedManager.GetPreview method.
- Add the video attachment to the Attachment property of the SocialPostCreationData object that's used to create the post.

[ [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn232144.aspx) ] Detailed Steps and [Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn232144.aspx#bkmk_addVideo)

---

**Newsfeed (Programatically) - Attaching Documents**

In terms of implementation, you can embed documents into posts by doing the following:

- Get the SocialAttachment object that represents the document attachment by using the SocialFeedManager.GetPreview method.
- Add the document attachment to the Attachment property of the SocialPostCreationData object that's used to create the post.

[ [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn232144.aspx) ] Detailed Steps and [Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn232144.aspx#bkmk_addDoc)